# Translate one line please from python to ruby

Tags: python, ruby, sockets, struct, ip

Need to calculate IP => int just like in here:

https://bitbucket.org/lorien/django-ipgeo/src/d19648c9b14f/ipgeo/models.py
but in ruby.

I'm pretty new in ruby, so cannot translate this into ruby:

```
number = struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]
```

*struct*, *socket* are python std, *ip* is a string like '127.0.0.1'

Comment: To the close voter: In what way is this question "difficult to determine"?  This question is very, very clear and precise. He wants the equivalent ruby code for that particular line in python - and there is nothing ambiguous about that line in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby comes with an [`ipaddr`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/index.html) module that specifies an `IPAddr` class that can return a representation as an integer.

```
require 'ipaddr'

addr = IPAddr.new '127.0.0.1'
print addr.to_i
```

Here it is in `irb`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > require 'ipaddr'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > addr = IPAddr.new '127.0.0.1'
 => #<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > addr.to_i
 => 2130706433
```

Comment: so simple and so magic. it's proves again python is more explicit: i can guess what happens in the line. but it's so easy in ruby :)